# Symfony 3: Translation: Webprofiler vs. Console Output

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

I'm currently working on the translations part of a project. Now I'm very confused by the different debug outputs from Symfony in the Webprofiler vs. the Console.

The Webprofiler always gives me correct informations (messages are defined, fallback is used):

[image]

---

The Console Output, however, is pretty unsatisfying and doesn't seem to recognize that Ids are missing and 1 fallback is used...

```
C:\xampp_htdocs\project>console debug:translation fr AppBundle
 ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------------------
  State      Domain     Id               Message Preview (fr)
 ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------------------
   unused    messages   xyzrole.delete   BONJOUR
 ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------------------
```

I'm just trying to get the translation debugging to work as it's explained here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#debugging-translations

The messages are stored in `app\Resources\AppBundle\translations`.

I'm working under Win 7 and Xampp. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: the webprofiler is talking about the en locale, the console command you lauch is about the fr.

Comment: you know this bundle? [link](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle). This bundle provides a web interface to manage the whole issue of translations

Comment: @Matteo it's the fallback tab in the Webprofiler, which is `en`, the locale is set to `fr`